# How to use extern C in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, c, extern

I am making a program in c++.
When I try to compile it, I have a problem:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -fshort-wchar -c src/kernel.cpp -o lib/kernel.o
src/kernel.cpp:5:8: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
5 | extern "C" void _start(FrameBuffer* frameBuffer, PSF1_FONT* psf1_font)
```

This is my main file:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "BasicRenderer.h"


extern "C" void _start(FrameBuffer* frameBuffer, PSF1_FONT* psf1_font) // The error is here
{

    BasicRenderer newRenderer;
    newRenderer.CursorPosition = {15, 50};
    newRenderer.Print(frameBuffer, psf1_font, 0xffffffff, "Hello World!");

    return ;
}
```

I'm running that on linux
How to fix this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You source file is compiled as C language. The `extern "C"` attributes is only in C++ language. So just remove it, or compile with **g++**

Comment: @prapin: `gcc` is smart enough to compile `.cpp` files as C++ unless explicitly instructed otherwise with the `-x` switch, and the “unqualified-id” mentioned in the error message is a C++ thing, an identifier without `::`. The problem may be in `BasicRenderer.h`.

Comment: Look in `BasicRenderer.h` for a problem. You may have a declaration in it that is not terminated with a semicolon or some similar error.

Comment: My program is a C++ code
I looked in BasicRenderer.h, and I have no errors

Comment: @Delavel - Can you at least try to invoke `g++ -ffreestanding -fshort-wchar -c src/kernel.cpp -o lib/kernel.o` and tell us what happens?

Comment: I have this:
`error: expected initializer before ‘void’
extern C void _start(FrameBuffer* frameBuffer, PSF1_FONT* psf1_font)`

Comment: for a start: identifiers starting with underscore are forbidden. second: you use `extern "C"` _only_ in C++, it doesn't exist in C. which brings me to finally... you might want to use `g++` to compile instead of `gcc`?

Comment: I tried with gcc and g++, but I have errors:
**error: expected unqualified-id before string constant**
and
**error: expected initializer before ‘void’**
I removed the underscore

Comment: *My program is a C++...* Then why are you using C's `#include <stdint.h>` instead of C++'s `#include <cstdint>`?  The bug is probably in `BasicRenderer.h`, which you have not provided.

Comment: I found!
C’était un petit problème de compilateur, ce n’était pas la bonne version.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating a program from c to c++ with gcc, you don't need to add
`extern "C"`

To fix the error, simply delete `extern "C"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but I found the problem. It was just a compilation problem.